# Setting up a centos 5 production server from scratch

Tags: centos, centos5

I have got a new dedicated server. I have to set it up for my live website.
I have read basic things like yum install php mysql etc. But with each tutorial, there's notice that don't use it for production server. Can anybody guide me in setting it up for production use.
Here's what i need:
Php,Mysql,ftp access, multiple accounts,
I will not be using cpanel. I can use webmin..

Answer (score 2):

When you say "live website" do you mean on the internet?

Sorry hardeep, but if you've only "read basic things", then you're just asking for trouble setting up your own server on the internet - and potentially creating problems for everyone else out there. How would you feel if you had to be operated on, and the surgeon told you he'd "read some basic things" about appendectomies? It takes years to learn how to set up a system securely - and you never stop learning. The cheapest route to doing this safely is to pay for a hosted service - let someone else (who hopefully knows what they are doing) worry about hardening the server, installing/patching the software, maintaining backups etc.

If the server will not be exposed on the internet....that's a different matter. But you should still take every sensible precaution to making your system secure. The bare minimum you should be doing is presented in the [SANS Linux Security Checklist](http://www.sans.org/score/checklists/linuxchecklist.pdf). But you really need to understand why each of these requirements should be implemented for them to have any value for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you use the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), if you want use more recent versions of useful packages.